# Stream to a few servers streamer proxy

Tags: nginx, http-live-streaming, haproxy, rtmp

I am streaming live event using nginx with rtmp module with OBS but now I have a lot viewers and my server is not enough. I want to add 2 server for my viewers using HLS and OBS to trasnmit and video.js to see in the browser

```
                     --- streamer server1 ---|
OBS ---- Encoder-----|                       |----> proxy http 
         Proxy       --- streamer server2 ---|
```

I am using nginx. Is it posibble to do ?

TIA

Comment: OBS---Proxy----server1 & Server2

Answer (score 0):

What you have diagrammed is possible and provides HA but you could scale a lot higher using caching. That is the whole point of HLS, it is compatible with all the HTTP caching infrastructure. Depending on size of your pipe the reverse-caching-proxy should be able to handle a huge number of requests.

```
OBS ------- streamer server (nginx) ----> reverse-caching-proxy (nginx) or CDN Provider -> Viewer
```